# Silverlight WebRequest fails with "The URI prefix is not recognized"

Tags: silverlight, httpwebrequest, uri, webrequest

I have a silverlight library that is supposed to get make a web service request and receive an xml response:

```
   Uri uri = new Uri("http://some_server:51306/getStuff.xml?id=14");            
   WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
```

However, WebRequest.Create(uri) fails with the exception "The URI prefix is not recognized".

Note that I am running the program using a unit test from a non-silverlight dll. I need to build a test suite for the app!

Any ideeas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the .Web project as the default startup project instead of the Silverlight project

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the second parameter to the Uri constructor?

```
 Uri uri = new Uri("http://some_server:51306/getStuff.xml?id=14", UriKind.Absolute);
```