# Problem accessing localhost URI from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf, rest, service, azure

(repost because of SO outage; apologies if the other one re-appears)

I'm building a Silverlight app that will run on Azure. My VS solution has two projects: the web role and the Silverlight. The web role has a Service that works. (I can go to `localhost:88/expenseservice.svc/expenses` and get the data I want.)

I am trying to access that data from Silverlight:

```
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        WebClient data = new WebClient();
        data.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(data_DownloadStringCompleted);
        Uri dataSource = new Uri("localhost:88/expenseservice.svc/expenses");
        data.DownloadStringAsync(dataSource);
    }

    void data_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.InnerException.Message);
            return;
        }

        // ...

    }
```

However, this does not work. The message box shows the error:

> The URI prefix is not recognized.

Here is the full exception:

```
e.Error.InnerException = {System.NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.
   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringAsync(Uri address, Object userToken)}
```

Is it complaining about `localhost`? Am I supposed to be doing something differently? Perhaps this is what "Add Service Reference" is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the prefix is not recognized because it is missing. The prefix should be the first part that describes what kind of service your URI is pointing to. For example `http://` of `svn://` and so on..

Just add the right one and it should work.. (I've never used Silverlight neither anything Microsoftish so I'm just guessing)

Comment: I think you are not getting the point. What kind of service is online over port 88? a webserver?

Comment: This can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246735/silverlight-webrequest-fails-with-the-uri-prefix-is-not-recognized

Comment: haha I'm definitely not getting the point. It's an ASP web role hosted on the Azure dev server.